# Getting a permission denied while invoking remote server script and command in if loop is not working properly

Tags: linux, permissions, aix

We have two servers, one is aix and other is linux, so from our linux server, i am trying to invoked script that is located on aix to minimise script execution time.
code:
On linux machine

```
ssh user@$ip "sudo -u user2 'bash -c .  /path (loading user profile) ; sh script.sh' "
```

On Aix machine:

script.sh

```
#/bin/bash
. /path [loading user profile]

db2 connect to db_name

db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l  > state_log

db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l  > normal_log



var1=$(cat state_log)

var2=$(cat normal_log)

if [[ "${var1}" == "${var2}" ]]
then
echo " tablespaces are normal "
else
echo "tablespaces are not normal"
fi
```

---

script is working fine on aix machine, however I am getting a error on linux machine

```
cat: cannot open state log and normal log : permission denied( even after giving
Full permission to file)
```

----++++New changes++++++

As per your advise in comment section, i have done some changes.

Now on linux machine below code i am using for invoking script on remote server.

```
ssh user@$ip 'sudo -u user2 bash script.sh'
```

On Aix machine:

`script.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash 
. /path [user profile]
 if [[ `db2 connect to db_name |  db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l` == `db2 connect to db_name` | db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l` ]]
then 
echo " tablespaces are normal " 
else 
echo "tablespaces are not normal" 
fi
```

script is now, not working fine on aix machine, Sometime it fetches value of first command in if loop and sometime second. I am not getting what's wrong with the code. Thanks in advance for all of your help !!!

+++++++New changes 2 +++++++

I have done following changes in aix script and it works for me.

#/bin/bash
. /path [loading user profile]

db2 connect to db_name

db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l  > full_path_of_file1

db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l  > full_path_of_file2

var1=$(cat full_path_of_file1)

var2=$(cat full_path_of_file2)

if [[ "${var1}" == "${var2}" ]]
then
echo " tablespaces are normal "
else
echo "tablespaces are not normal"
fi

Kind of weird behaviour of AIX OS but it works.

Comment: Can you try adjusting your SSH command to `bash script.sh db_name`? The default `sh` shell might be pointing to an older shell that cannot understand bash syntax.

Comment: @Haxiel that was command line argument bash script.sh db_name... If you see script.sh there is a command db2 connect to $1. Now I have changed it for more clear understanding. Any help from anyone would be appreciate

Comment: I was trying to clarify a different point. In your SSH command, you are executing the script using `sh script.sh` (the arguments are not relevant). That executes the script using the `sh` shell, but you have written your script using the `bash` shell. Most modern Linux distros have `sh` to be the same as `bash`, but I believe AIX comes with a very old version of `ksh` as the default shell. So, specifying `bash script.sh` in your SSH command line could resolve the issue.

Comment: It would be better if you _did not_ anntotate code and error messages with inline comments. The error message from `cat` at the end seems to refer to a file called (literally) `state log and normal log`.

Comment: @Haxiel The bash-specific code comes _after_ any use of `cat` in the script.

Comment: What is odd is that the two files are presumably correctly truncated and written at the start of the script, and then immediately unreadable later. What is the output of `ls -l state_log normal_log`? It may be that they lack the read permission bits for the current user.  As [roaima says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721153/116858), a better idea may in any case be to capture the line counts into variables directly instead of writing them to intermediate files.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's more likely to be a lack of permission on `user`'s home directory while running under `sudo` as `user2`. There's no `-H` so `sudo` won't necessarily have switched to the target user's home directory. Please see my answer that includes this suggestion

Comment: @roaima I don't know about that. In the user's original script, it's the same effective user that writes to the two files from `wc -l` as reads from them later with `cat`, and the redirection from `wc -l` (presumably) succeeds while the `cat` fails.  Hmm... maybe we're saying the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ssh user@$ip "sudo -u user2 'bash -c .  /path (loading user profile) ; sh script.sh' "
```

with

```
ssh user@$ip sudo -u user2 bash script.sh
```

You don't need to invoke `./path`  outside the script because the first the the script does is invoke it itself. At that point the line can be vastly simplified.

If that doesn't resolve the permissions error, ensure that you're in the correct directory for your script

```
ssh user@$ip sudo -Hu user2 bash script.sh
```

Better defensive coding would be to use directory paths in your script for the files `state_log` and `normal_log`, explicitly setting the necessary directory in which to write them.

If you have shown your complete script, you can potentially further optimise it by not even writing to files but instead capturing the `db2` outputs directly into the two variables:

```
#/bin/bash
. /path    # Load user profile

db2 connect to db_name
var1=$(db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l)
var2=$(db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l)

if [[ $var1 -eq $var2 ]]
then
    echo "tablespaces are normal"
else
    echo "tablespaces are not normal"
fi
```

Although I'm not entirely sure why `$var` and `$var2` would ever be different in this situation.

Comment: As per your advise, i have done some changes

ssh user@$ip 'sudo -u user2 bash script.sh'

On Aix machine:

script.sh

    #/bin/bash
    . /path [user profile]
 
  if [[ `db2 connect to db_name |  db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l` == `db2 list tablespaces | grep -i state | wc -l` ]
    then
    echo " tablespaces are normal "
    else
    echo "tablespaces are not normal"
    fi
script is now not working fine on aix machine, 
Sometym it fetches value of first command in if loop and sometym second. I am not getting what's wrong with the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried the way, you have explained, however there was still it was not able fetch value in to variable. I have tried other way around and it works.

Comment: @Geek I'm pleased to hear that _something_ works. You forgot to explain what went wrong when you tried to use my suggested code (errors, etc), and "_the other way_" isn't specific enough to identify what worked for you

Comment: Hi roima
Sorry for late reply, i have added new changes which I have made in script which works for me. Again appreciated buddy for your help. Now I have another new problem, i will post a new question, as this thread kind of jumbled

Comment: Where I can get this option, i am newbie to stack exchange.

Comment: @Geek read this [how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Done, thanks edgar